# How do I keep views alive like UITabBar applications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am creating an app with different views as you can see in this screenshot. [image: http://i.gyazo.com/f98661c649e4ba617057dd4ba7c21e7d.png]

However when I tap on "Transitions" it just loads the view again with `viewDidLoad` it does that every time so it always resets upon opening. But when you have a tabbed application it just loads it with `viewDidLoad` then whenever you open it again it just loads `viewDidAppear` since it already loaded.

Does anyone know how I can keep the controller alive like in a tabbed application ?

*Image of tabbed application - http://s1.ibtimes.com/sites/www.ibtimes.com/files/styles/v2_article_large/public/2013/06/18/ios-7-notonthisphone-2.PNG

Here's how the view loads now.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row];

    // This undoes the Zoom Transition's scale because it affects the other transitions.
    // You normally wouldn't need to do anything like this, but we're changing transitions
    // dynamically so everything needs to start in a consistent state.
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1);

    if ([menuItem isEqualToString:@"Transitions"]) {
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = self.transitionsNavigationController;
    } else if ([menuItem isEqualToString:@"Settings"]) {
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MESettingsNavigationController"];
    }


    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}
```

Decided to share my files with all of you if someone is an expert in this (clearly I'm not one of them) : http://www.mediafire.com/download/1q6n01514bf78jo/Sldiing_App.zip

Answer (score 1):

Well, keep them.

Maintain some container (array or individual properties/ivars etc) and keep references to them. Then, when the user tapps on "transitions", do not re-create the views and their controllers but put them back into place.

You may need to maintain each view controllers sub-view-controllers call hierarchy and manipulate the navigation controllers navigation stack (see docs for the viewControllers property of UIViewController). 
It is a bit of work though and does not come for free.

Alternatively, if you do not have a navigation controller involved or do not need to stack more view controllers on top of your bunch of view controllers that you want to keep alive, then you could just try to move them off the screen (To negative coordinates or beyond the windows' boundaries. But don't use constants for that. We all don't know what screen sizes future devices will have. Fetch the boundaries from the actual window on runtime.)

Comment: Ohh jeez, sounds really confusing for a beginner like me X.X. Do you know about any sample that I could download and experiment with.

Comment: No, I don't. Do you use a navigation controller at all? And keep in mind that UIViewControllers, in the end, are just objects like others.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am using a navigation controller, but still not sure (sounds silly I know), you can download the project that I have set up here http://www.mediafire.com/download/1q6n01514bf78jo/Sldiing_App.zip

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're tapping on "transitions" I assume you're doing an alloc/init of your view controller and then pushing it to whatever view stack you have for the main view. Instead, alloc/init a global view controller when your side menu loads, and push that onto your stack when you tap on "transitions" instead of creating a new one every time (this assumes that your menu persists and isn't loaded every time it comes up as well)